# ComboBox with multiple columns, Column Name "sku" and Column Number "17"

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to create a two column ComboBox.

The plan is to select "sku" in the ComboBox and pass "17" (derived from column Q1) to a sort procedure.

Row A contains column names, In this case "sku" lives in cell "Q1".

I have ten sheets to sort all with different column names and numbers of total columns.  So I cannot hard code anything.  I need to select "sku" and pass "17" to the sort subroutine.

I believe that I am loading the ComboBox correctly.  I have 187 columns, the counter i keeps counting past 187 until I get a type mismatch.

I have looked at this too long, until I can't see the woods for the trees :-)

**Sample Data for Row A**

upc post_title  post_name   ID  post_excerpt    post_content    post_status menu_order  post_date   post_parent post_author comment_status  stock   downloadable    virtual visibility  sku stock_status

**This is the code I have now:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Me
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
      .Show
    End With

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim Cell As Variant

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim lngLastColumn As Long

    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    Me.ComboBox2.ColumnCount = 2

    lngLastColumn = Worksheets("BirdFeet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    For Each Cell In Range("A1:" & Split(Cells(, lngLastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & lngLastColumn)          
        With Me.ComboBox2
            For i = 0 To lngLastColumn - 1        
                .AddItem Cell
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cell.Column
            Next i                
        End With
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: which line is giving you the error? If it is the line `.AddItem Cell` then check the value of that cell. The cell may have a formula error or some other kind of unacceptable value. Also If row 1 has headers then change `lngLastColumn = Worksheets("BirdFeet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count` to `lngLastColumn = Worksheets("BirdFeet").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` to get the last column

Comment: Also I am curious about the line `Range("A1:" & Split(Cells(, lngLastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & lngLastColumn)` I would have expected something like `Range("A1:" & Split(Cells(, lngLastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow)?`

Comment: I replaced the lngLastColumn with your suggestion.  I also replaced the Range line.  The Range statement tells me that the "argument not optional" in a compile error.  What is still happening is that the Sub runs for a very long time and then I get the type mismatch error.  It is not in the .additem area.  but I cannot locate it with the debugger as it happens very far out in the columns.  I went ahead and deleted the first 5,000 columns past my data with no change in Type Mismatch, "Run-time Error '-2147352571 (80020005)': is the run time error.

Comment: i (lngLastColumn) is counting up to 187 and then resetting to 0 and then it keeps running over and over.  I have added () to make it clear this is a subtraction ...For i = 0 To (lngLastColumn - 1) with no effect.  i keeps counting to 187 and then resetting to 0. Then it keeps running until I get the Type Mismatch error.

Comment: I'm struggling.  RowSource seems to work only for rows.  Here I need to get the columns as in A1:R1.  This is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: ok forget everything and tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm tired, so when I get tired I go back to the basics.  I started from scratch and got further in the last half hour than I did all day.

This is how I am now loading the 2-Dimensional array.  It is loading column names and a second column with the associated column number.  The number is based upon number of loops through the read cycle.

This is the code I have now.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Me
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
      .Show
    End With

    Dim intColumns As Integer, i As Integer    
    intColumns = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("BirdFeet").Rows(1))

    Dim ColumnNames() As String  
    ReDim ColumnNames(1, intColumns)

    For i = 0 To intColumns - 1    
        ColumnNames(0, i) = Cells(1, i + 1).value        
        ColumnNames(1, i) = i + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```